# Get steps and page. OpenCart

Tags: php, opencart

I am trying to get $steps and $page.

I tried this:

```
$steps = $myAPI->cleanPost($_POST['steps']);
$page = $myAPI->cleanPost($_POST['page']);
```

But i don't get something.

In PrestaShop we did it like this:

```
$page = (trim(Tools::getValue('page')) > 0) ? trim(Tools::getValue('page')) : 0;
$steps = trim(Tools::getValue('steps'));
```

And in Magento like this:

```
$page = (trim($app->getRequest()->getParam('page')) > 0) ? trim($app->getRequest()->getParam('page')) : 0;
$steps = trim($app->getRequest()->getParam('steps'));
```

Does someone know how I can do this with OpenCart?

Thanks

Comment: Did you read opencart documentation before? Cause I see you're posting several questions for it. First of all you have to read about "how to develop opencart modules": http://docs.opencart.com/developer/module/ Second: you have to replace your superglobal variables with opencart wrapper `$this->request->post['steps']`

Comment: Thanks. Should it be like this: $steps = $myAPI->cleanPost($this->request->post['steps']);?

Comment: Yes indeed. You have to refactor your code to be in 'opencart-style'

Comment: Okay thank you. Do you also know how i can get my password for the login in 'OpenCart-style?'

Comment: You can't get password - only password's hash

Comment: oh. I am building a login. How can i do that?

Comment: I created a new question. For the login and getting the password right. Here you can see all my code. Can you take a look for me? thanks! This is the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43570980/opencart-login-function

Comment: I changed the $steps to this: $steps = $myAPI->cleanPost($this->request->post['steps']); but know I am getting this error message: PHP Fatal error:  Using $this when not in object context in /home/key2demo/domains/key2datafeed.com/public_html/ocdemoshops/oc23/key2publish/k2p_api_OCwriter.php on line 186. Can you help me fix this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142398/discussion-between-alex-slipknot-and-stefwinter).